# Why is this TikZ pattern spilling outside the path it fills?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[pattern=horizontal lines] (0,0) -- (2,2) to[out=90,in=180] (4,5) -- (7,5) -- (7,0) -- cycle;
  \fill[pattern=north east lines] (0,0) -- (2,2) to[out=0,in=270] (4,5) -- (0,5) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image: bad pattern fill]

The "north east lines" pattern spills out to the right of the path it's supposed to be filling, which is definitely not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't replicate this on MikTeX 2.9, pdflatex, TikZ CVS version, Sumatra and Acrobat. Might be a viewer issue

Comment: Oh, weird. I think you're right that it might be a viewer issue. I see the overflow in evince, but not with xpdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a rendering bug in poppler, since xpdf renders the diagram correctly. I've reported this as [Bug 61737](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61737) at https://bugs.freedesktop.org.